# Changing calendar view based on timezone

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

[See in this image the schedule meeting is highlighted now this is for India timezone now if i open the same calendar in USA timezone the schedule should get changed according to there time zone so the calendar view should also be changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UyWb.png)I need to change the calendar view according to the timezone say for example if i am in India and I schedule a meeting from 3-4 pm so in accordingly the calendar will display when we are in India but if I am in USA or Paris the meeting that I schedule from 3-4 pm will be displayed in their calendar view differently.

Currently I have this code

```
final Date date = new Date();
final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));

currentstartDate = formatter.format(date);

currentendDate = formatter.format(date);
```

I am getting timezone from other bean and it is coming here as checked when debug

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using SimpleDateFormat?

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Complete code here:
    package general;

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateTimeTZ {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    Date date1 = isoFormat.parse("03/01/2016 09:01 AM");
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Mumbai"));

    isoFormat.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    System.out.println("Current Date and Time in IST time zone: " + isoFormat.format(date1));

    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    isoFormat.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    System.out.println("Current Date and Time in SGT time zone: " + isoFormat.format(date1));

    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
    isoFormat.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    System.out.println("Current Date and Time in JST time zone: " + isoFormat.format(date1));

}

}
```

Output:

Current Date and Time in IST time zone: 01 Mar 2016 03:31:00 GMT

Current Date and Time in SGT time zone: 01 Mar 2016 11:31:00 SGT

Current Date and Time in JST time zone: 01 Mar 2016 12:31:00 JST

Comment: Actually what i want is the calendar view should change according to the timezone in which schedules have been made.In this we are just changing from one timezone to another

Comment: Can you share output from your program and indicate what you were looking to see?

Comment: I have added one image for better understanding.Just check

Comment: how are you displaying the time on the frame you shared in the image? can you add the relevant code? I am assuming you have a user profile setting which has TZ local to the user. If yes, can you not call setTimeZone function as shown above?